# How to add DIV tag inside Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm trying to insert a div tag inside ajax but I just can't figure out how. So far this is my code:

```
function userLogin(){
var email = $("#login_username_text").val();
var password = $("#login_password_text").val(); 
var login_url = connect_url+'retrieveUser.php?email='+email+"&password="+password;

$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: login_url,
        async: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'userCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) { 
            is_logged = (json[0].logged==0)?false:true;
            alert(is_logged);
            alert(email);
            alert(password);

            if(is_logged==false){
                alert ("Invalid Username and Password");   //I want to change 
//this into a div tag so that it will be displayed on the page itself and so that
//I can add CSS codes here
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {

        }
}); 
}
```

I tried `document.getElementById('login_invalid').innerText = 'Invalid Username and Password.';` but not working... any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a div with id login_invalid on your page?

Comment: console.log(is_logged), and let know the result. EDIT: Since you are already using jquery, make it $("#login_invalid").html("Invalid"); rather than using getElementById.

Comment: I'd suggest [looking for some basic DOM manipulation tutorials](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dom+manipulation+tutorial+-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerText` isn't an universally supported property. And while the more standardized [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) is useful to read the content it's better to use innerHTML to replace the content of a div.

Assuming your div exists, you should use

```
document.getElementById('login_invalid').innerHTML = 'Invalid Username and Password.';
```

or, as you obviously use jQuery

```
$('#login_invalid').html('Invalid Username and Password.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("<div/>", {
    "class": "test",
    text: "Invalid Username and Password",
    }).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the div tag and add class to it, it will work. If you want to add Id to this element you can use .attr('attribute_name','attribute_value') as follow:

```
if(is_logged==false){
      $('body').append('<div>Invalid Username and Password</div>').addClass("error").attr('id', 'login_invalid');
 }
```